# How to indicate a specific path to julia libdl find_library()?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to indicate a specific path to `find_library()`. Based on the [doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Libdl/), `find_library()`

> Searches for the first library in names in the paths in the locations list, DL_LOAD_PATH, or system library paths (in that order) which can successfully be dlopen'd`

My library `foo.dll` is located at `\library\` unfortunately, I don't know how to specify it !

#### 1st try : Set the `location` inside find_library()

```
const _LIB = find_library("foo.dll", raw"\library")` gave me the following error : 
MethodError: no method matching joinpath(::Char, ::String) Closest candidates are: joinpath(::AbstractString, ::AbstractString...)
```

#### 2nd Try : Set `DL_LOAD_PATH`

```
DL_LOAD_PATH = raw"../library" (or `DL_LOAD_PATH = raw"/library`) but then : `_LIB==""`
```

NB : The dll is readable : actually, my code can find it if i place it in my windows path, but i would like to make something more portable)

**EDIT** :

**my path :**

```
.
├── library
│   └── foo.dll
└── src
    ├── MyPackage.jl
    └── types.jl
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a solution thanks to [this thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-indicate-a-specific-path-to-julia-libdl-find-library/67794/6)

The second argument of `find_library()` is a `Vector` thus a solution could be :

```
const _LIB = find_library("foo.dll", [joinpath(@__DIR__, "..", "library")])
```

(with [] around the second argument)